# What Encryption Algorithm does SQL Server CE use?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, sql-server-ce

Including the following in a connection string to create a SQL Server CE database will cause the created database to be encrypted. However I need to know what encryption algorithm is used, and how this differs across different operating systems?

```
  Encrypt Database = True;
  Password = 'password';
```

The following resource under the heading "Encryption algorithms" seems to Triple-DES will be used on all operating systems prior to Windows Vista SP1, then AES265 on operating systems above this? I'm not sure if I'm interoperating the table correctly or if this table even relates to SQL Server CE.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd125380(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/laxmi/archive/2008/04/15/sql-server-compact-database-file-security.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/07/07/introducing-sql-server-compact-4-0-the-next-gen-embedded-database-from-microsoft.aspx